# No sandbox with the production org.

Tags: sandbox, production

I have client who have purchased a salesforce licence. He provided me production org. When I asked for sandbox  he replied that there is not sandbox when he purchased this licence. Is there any licence which do not contain sandbox. With out sandbox where do we code and add to the production org. Can anyone here help me out to get the solution. If sandbox is there then how can we get it? Please do help me.

Comment: If you're using Contact Edition, Group Edition, or Professional Edition, you can't use certain types of code, either. Triggers and Apex Code aren't available in these organizations. Only Enterprise Edition and above enjoy these features.

Answer (score 5):

Sandboxes aren't part of the CONTACT, GROUP and PROFESSIONAL Editions. In the [Help (Sandbox Overview)](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=create_test_instance.htm&language=en_US) you can see they are only available for: Enterprise, Performance, Unlimited, and Database.com Editions

But in your case it looks like the customer doesn't know how to create a sandbox. Therefore just create a new sandbox..

To find out which edition you are using, visit the "Home" tab and check your browser's "title" bar.
[image]

Comment: In addition to what you've state, the *Type* of sandbox can vary. Some orgs may decide they only want to pay for a partial sandbox instead of a full sandbox.

Comment: so @Christain how can I create a sandbox for the production account when there is no sandbox available. And please let me know where can I go and find out which Editions is this.